# Using Maps.directionFinder and Maps.geoCoder in an Apps Script bound to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

We are using the Maps classes in an Apps Script bound to a google sheet.  We experience no problems with the GeoCoder.  But with the DirectionFinder we get intermittent OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors.  These errors will occur if we have done no other calls in the last 24 hours and if we have done a few.  They will occur without any distinguishable pattern.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Is anyone else using your API key?  Also, are you familiar with exponential backoff?  [link]https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#exponential-backoff

Comment: Thanks Rob.  We were not, now thanks to you we are.   Also, we solved our  issue.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out.  We stopped using the Maps classes in App Scripts and started accessing the Web Service via URLFetch().  Everything is now working as advertised.